# API or directly to AWS?

Tags: aws-sdk

I have a pretty straight forward question. If someone are to do a commercial Android project using AWS, is it best practice to build a RESTlet or Protocoll Buffers API (a server/service) for the app to communicate with which then send database requests to AWS, or do they skip the API and just communicate with the DynamoDB service directly which would be less code but not as cute?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that decoupling your app from DynamoDB will help with scaling. What if you decide to not use DynamoDB anymore? You only have to change the service, and that can be transparent to the app and its users.

If your app can tolerate it, you could try an asynchronous approach. This will decrease latency and increase flexibility/scalability. An example of this: app pushes an event to an SNS topic. From there you can have SQS queues subscribed to this topic to retain these messages, and then have a Lambda function/web app that processes the queue.

Comment: Hmmm.. I am trying to understand your asynchronous example but do not really get it I think. Is there a easy way to explain it?

Comment: Well, put simply: Your app would produce a message for a consumer to process.

Here's an example. I highly recommend this book, AWS In Action.
https://github.com/AWSinAction/code/tree/master/chapter12/url2png

In this example, the index.js and worker.js are beanstalk apps. The worker.js gets SQS messages posted to it from a queue (you can configure this in beanstalk)

Comment: Oooooh..so u mean that the service could theoretically put all messages in a queue first when they arrive and then throw the actual work over on threads to make the service able to handle requests even if another one is being processed?

Comment: Right. And if a worker fails, the message stays in the queue and can be picked up by another worker to try.